# An unexpected error occurred while downloading the dictation language

Tags: macos, voice-dictation

I'm on Yosemite and trying to download Enhanced dictation language files for English (USA). Default language is set to English (Australia) I don't know why.

I'm getting this error. I have also tried the solution given here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5480134 but it doesn't solve the problem.

Can anybody here help?

[image]

Comment: Could you check your settings in System Preferences > Language & Region… Make sure to have in the "prefered language" list "U.S. English" (it doesn't have to be the primary)…